# Quadrilateral inscribed in a circle

Tags: geometry

If a quadrilateral $ABCD$ is inscribed in a circle, prove that:

$$\frac{AC}{BD}=\frac{AB\cdot AD+BC\cdot CD}{AB\cdot BC+CD\cdot AD}$$

P.S: All my attempt is getting bigger and bigger and messy. I'm still trying.

Comment: For Googling purposes, such a quadrilateral is said to be _cyclic_. Wikipedia has an entire page on them, for instance.

Comment: Isn't the denominator BD? Looks like a theorem I have proven before

Comment: @Rohan: It is $BD$. Where did you prove that?

Comment: Please see below.

Comment: Wikipedia refers to this result on their page on cyclic quadrilaterals as "Ptolemy's second theorem" and gives a citation to that effect. @Rohan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that, as a consequence of the Law of Sines, a triangle $\triangle ABC$ with circumdiameter $d$ has sides of length
$$|\overline{BC}| = d\sin A \qquad |\overline{CA}| = d\sin B \qquad |\overline{AB}| = d\sin C$$
The product of a triangle's three side-lengths, then, is nicely proportional to its area
$$|\overline{AB}||\overline{BC}||\overline{CA}| = 2 d \cdot \frac{1}{2}|\overline{AB}||\overline{BC}|\sin B = 2 d \; |\triangle ABC| \qquad (\star)$$

With $d$ the circumdiameter of the cyclic quadrilateral $\square ABCD$, the relation to be proven easily reduces via $(\star)$ to
$$2d \; \left(\; |\triangle ABC| + |\triangle ADC| \;\right) = 2 d \; \left(\; |\triangle BAD| + |\triangle BCD| \;\right)$$
and we see that each sum of triangle areas simply gives the area of $\square ABCD$ itself.

Comment: Nice idea! Thanks! Let's see if someone has another solution. If not, that will be the chosen.